# join object with the same name into one item

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to join the objects with the same name into one item array and i don't know how to do it.

I have an array like this :

```
  [ 
   { name: 'core/core.js',
     item: [ [Object] ] },
   { name: 'users/admin.js',
     item: [ [Object] ] },
   { name: 'users/admin.js',
     item: [ [Object] ] }
  ]
```

and i want to have something similar to this :

```
  [ 
   { name: 'core/core.js',
     item: [ [Object] ] },
   { name: 'users/admin.js',
     item: [
       [ [Object] ],
       [ [Object] ]
     ]
   },
  ]
```

Here is my code:

```
const pathFile = [
  { name: 'core/core.js', item: [{ name: 'core' }] },
  { name: 'users/admin.js', item: [{ name: 'admin1' }] },
  { name: 'users/admin.js', item: [{ name: 'admin2' }] },
];
const obj = pathFile.reduce((a, name) => {
  if (!a[name]) {
    a[name] = { name, files: [] };
  }
  a[name].files.push({ name });
  return a;
}, {});
const arr = Object.values(obj);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Comment: What have you tried? We are not here to do your homework...

Comment: yes, i tried but it's not working, i just updated my question with the code i'm trying

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález the example posted seems pretty clear (or it does now).

Comment: @MarkMeyer Yep, now it has a `Here is my code:` with the code he tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using the wrong value for keys inside your `reduce()` loop. In your code `name` refers to the whole object inside the `reduce` so you would need to use `name.name` for the key because each item, which you are calling `name` inside the reduce loop has a `name` property. It might be better to use a different parameter name such as `curr` so it's clearer.

```js
const pathFile = [{ name: 'core/core.js', item: [{ name: 'core' }] },{ name: 'users/admin.js', item: [{ name: 'admin1' }] },{ name: 'users/admin.js', item: [{ name: 'admin2' }] },];

const obj = pathFile.reduce((a, curr) => {
    if (!a[curr.name])  a[curr.name] =  curr   
    else a[curr.name].item.push(...curr.item);
    return a;
}, {});
const arr = Object.values(obj);
console.log(arr)
```